# Как правильно разделить ассеты?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Имеется проект, для которого сделал мобильную версию. На мобильной версии не нужен полный набор внешних стилей и js библиотек, но парочка общих имеется. Мобильные ассеты в результирующих файлах общей версии тоже не нужны. Пробовал опцией stub исключать из общей версии, но тогда из неё исключаются общие библиотеки. Как обычно в таких ситуациях поступают?

```
/assets
  /javascripts
    application.js(main version)
    main_version_js_files
    /mobile_version_folder
      application.js
      some_js_files
  /stylesheets
    application.css
    main_version_css_files
    /mobile_version_folder
      application.css
      some_css_files
```

Общие внешние библиотеки лежат в vendors/assets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В application.js и .css основной версии изменил строку с `require tree .` на `require tree ./main`, все файлы относящиеся к этой версии перенес в поддиректорию main:

```
/assets
  /javascripts
    application.js(main version)
    /main
      main_version_js_files
    /mobile_version_folder
      application.js
      some_js_files
  /stylesheets
    application.css
    /main
      main_version_css_files
    /mobile_version_folder
      application.css
      some_css_files
```